# Meaning of グリッて

Tags: meaning, onomatopoeia

[image]

The character doesn't know how to ride a bike and tries to remember what his friend was doing when starting the vehicle.

He then says to himself :

> たしかここんとこを**グリッて**まわしてたような……

I can't find any info on グリッて, what does it mean?

Comment: I can't seem to find anything either. I think it could be an idea (if you can) to include a picture/scan of the actual sentence, just in case.

Well, I found this : http://doramani645.blog135.fc2.com/blog-entry-525.html but I am not sure it is related.

Comment: 「ぐるっと」とか「ぐるりと」みたいなもんです。

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%97) suggestsグリップ (adding プ to get "grip"), which might make sense in the context of this image.

Comment: I don't think グリップ is related & @Choco has the answer (which she should go ahead and post! Welcome back!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This グリって is a mimetic adverb (擬態語) which is basically the same as [グリグリ(と)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/64021/m0u/):

> 押さえつけながら強く回すさま。「ひじで肩を―（と）もむ」

It's similar to [グルグル(と)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/64340/m0u/%E3%81%90%E3%82%8B%E3%81%90%E3%82%8B/)/グルっと which describes how something rotates smoothly. But グリグリ refers to a more forceful, unsmooth movement/rotation.

Comment: I feel グリグリ when I rotate my notched mouse wheel back and forth.